# evaluation of execution speeds for various opcodes in EVM

Tags: evm, opcode, goethe

Using `traceTransaction` we can get the following data:

```
debug.traceTransaction("0x0cec118d22fbd572bf25c7e4143919e608989bec7da08512f2a6f3171df3b3b8")
{
  gas: 104030,
  returnValue: "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  structLogs: [{
      depth: 1,
      error: null,
      gas: 247189,
      gasCost: 3,
      memory: null,
      op: "PUSH1",
      pc: 0,
      stack: [],
      storage: {}
  }, {
      depth: 1,
      error: null,
      gas: 247186,
      gasCost: 3,
      memory: null,
      op: "PUSH1",
      pc: 2,
      stack: ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060"],
      storage: {}
  }, 
...
  {
      depth: 1,
      error: null,
      gas: 165970,
      gasCost: 0,
      memory: ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0", "532e204d61747468657700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "456e676c69736800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"],
      op: "RETURN",
      pc: 349,
      stack: ["00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000773b82a3", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020", "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0"],
      storage: {
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000: "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
        290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e563: "532e204d61747468657700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e564: "456e676c69736800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e565: "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c"
      }
  }]
}
```

Is there some way to get the amount of time it takes for each opcode (`op`) to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get every opcode executed time by changing source file, and rebuild, deploy to test. In [instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/instructions.go) file, there are all opcode, what you should do is add log, it's so simple. As follows:

1. Open local `instructions` source file, and the adding log you want to know executing time for every opcode. For instance, i added a log for opAdd instruction:

   ```
   func opAdd(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {
       var startTime = time.Now().UnixNano();
       x, y := stack.pop(), stack.pop()
       stack.push(math.U256(x.Add(x, y)))
       evm.interpreter.intPool.put(y)
       fmt.Println("execute opAdd consume = ",(time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime))
       return nil, nil
   }
   ```
2. Rebuild. At first go to go-ethereum dir and execute `make all` command in terminal. If everything is ok, some cmd had been generated in dir of 'build/bin'.
3. Run. executing command `geth` to go to console, and then check result of changing code. There are six opAdd ops for `traceTransaction` command.

   `execute opAdd consume =  186
   execute opAdd consume =  141
   execute opAdd consume =  107
   execute opAdd consume =  92
   execute opAdd consume =  127
   execute opAdd consume =  289`

Hope it helps ~

Comment: this approach is awesome, for sure I'm going to do this, but just now when I tried `make all` I got the error: 
`core/vm/instructions.go:37: undefined: time in time.Now
 core/vm/instructions.go:45: undefined: time in time.Now`

Comment: ok, nevermind- just had to `import ("time"...)`

Comment: where will these opcodes render? can I access them through the console at `geth attach ipc:/Users/s.matthew.english/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc`

Comment: man, it seems I can't get this to show up in the console output thru `attach`

Comment: Hi, if you had added log, cd `go-ethereum` dir, execute `./build/bin/geth datadir=/Users/s.matthew.english/Library/Ethereum/testnet console` to go to console, and then call `traceTransaction` method.

Comment: I got this one `Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use`, and specifying a different port like this `--port "35555"` also didn't work. why would I need to call the `traceTransaction` method?

Comment: You should have started a geth on other terminal, please kill process of owning 30303 port or a new port start~

Comment: hmm, but I think that's what I've done, I wanted to start it on testnet so I could call the function I deployed in a particular smart contract, I started `geth` like this `geth --cache=1048 --testnet --unlock '0xd7a9a61a480d458a1181e0563b07f944df4489a6' --rpc --rpcapi 'eth,net,web3' --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545 --etherbase '0xd7a9a61a480d458a1181e0563b07f944df4489a6' --mine`

Comment: Yes, did you success? you can execute `debug.traceTransaction(tx_hash)` command~

Comment: so, I think it worked, when I booted up the node it looked like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaKs8.jpg do you know why it has output those opcodes even before I've not executed any command?

Comment: There are many commands executed when you go to console. For instance, in [console](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/console/console.go) file, `Welcome` method  will be call when starting node, this methods include basic info of executed command compiled bytecode.

Comment: would there be a way to output this data only for opcodes of function/contracts that I call myself?

Comment: Actually, the front log ouput only when starting node(you enter console), this commands are used to checking version and environment, they are only executed once, don't interact your function/contract call.