# log output of modified function to geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, opcode

To analyze the execution time of different opcodes I've created the following modifications to the `go-ethereum` file [instructions.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/instructions.go):

```
func opAdd(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {

    // begin execution time tracking
    var startTime = time.Now().UnixNano();

    x, y := stack.pop(), stack.pop()
    stack.push(math.U256(x.Add(x, y)))

    evm.interpreter.intPool.put(y)

    // log ellapsed execution time
    fmt.Println("execute opAdd consume = ",(time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime))

    return nil, nil
}
```

I've attached to the client accordingly:

```
geth attach ipc:/Users/s.matthew.english/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
```

However, when I call a contract I've deployed to the `ropsten testnet` like so:

```
> var contractAbi = eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increment","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getIteration","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);

undefined

>  var myContract = contractAbi.at("0x8705C513da621a16fd1dEFc9dE8aE7CDEAD01Fb8");

undefined

> var getData = myContract.increment.getData(666);

undefined

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, 'hunter2');

true

> web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:"0x8705C513da621a16fd1dEFc9dE8aE7CDEAD01Fb8", from:"0xd7a9a61a480d458a1181e0563b07f944df4489a6", data: getData});
"0x506535adb4bf088a862f7e6194bf23c73bd2ad2086830bc028be766323ffef1c"

> myContract.address

"0x8705C513da621a16fd1dEFc9dE8aE7CDEAD01Fb8"

> myContract.getIteration()

668
```

But I don't see those opcode execution times anywhere.

How can I make sure to log them to a place where I can actually observe and examine them?

More generally, what is the procedure to ensure that a function will write output to the console?

Comment: doesn't work ? [https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23858/evaluation-of-execution-speeds-for-various-opcodes-in-evm/23861#23861](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23858/evaluation-of-execution-speeds-for-various-opcodes-in-evm/23861#23861)

Comment: yeah actually it works, maybe I should delete this one.

Comment: Hi @s.matthew.english - so this worked in the end? Might be worth removing the question if so, to keep it from adding to the "unanswered" metrics. (They contribute to overall "board health", though outside of a board's Beta, I'm unsure if these are used for anything... )